# How to use storyboard animations in .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, animation, storyboard, maui, .net-maui

I was wondering how to use [WPF-style storyboard animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) in .NET MAUI content pages. This spec (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/265) says that it is possible and an equivalent has implemented in MAUI but I don't have any idea how to use it.

Please could someone explain it, and provide a demo (if possible).

Comment: From that discussion, it sounds like what was implemented is [.Net Maui Animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/animation/basic).